# Combining two sorted arrays to form a new array of the same length

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of some fixed length N. I then want to randomly cut these two arrays using the same threshold value. I then want to glue the first part of the first array to the second part of the second array. This new array should still have the same size as the original arrays.

If my explanation is not clear, consider the following example:

We have the following two arrays

```
arr1 = [1,3,5,7,8,10]
arr2 = [2,4,5,7,8,11]
```

If I would choose 4 as a threshold value this would give the following new array

```
result = [1,3,4,5,7,8,11]
```

Which is clearly not of the same size as the original array. If however, we would choose 6 as a threshold value we would get

```
result = [1,3,5,7,8,11]
```

Which has the required size. Since I will be doing this calculation quite often and on quite large arrays I would like to know the most efficient method of doing this. I am writing this in python and would therefore prefer an answer using numpy methods.

Comment: If the length is odd, how will you determine how many to pick from `arr1` and `arr2` ?

Comment: looks like you want the solution to be dynamic enough to decide how many to pick from each array `arr1` and `arr2` such that it matches the length of the target array. Got it.

Comment: combine both arrays, create a set, sort ascending, then pick the values until index = length of array

Comment: Are your arrays always sorted ?

Comment: Yes, they are always sorted. But this is just to make sure that I can partition them based on a threshold value. I only want elements from the first array smaller than some value and elements from the second array larger than this value. The threshold value itself does not really matter but if multiple are possible I would prefer the one which divides both arrays as close as possible to splitting them in half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
# find the first index that arr1[idx] >= arr2[idx]
idx = np.argmax(np.array(arr1) >= arr2)

# for every i < idx <= j
# arr1[i] < arr2[i] < arr2[j]
# so the output is increasing
np.concatenate([arr1[:idx], arr2[idx:]])
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  8, 11])
```

And if you're interested in the threshold, it's `arr2[idx]`, becareful with the case `idx == len(arr1)`.

Comment: This seems to always choose the first possible index where the cut can happen. So while this does indeed satisfy my question, it would be better if I could cut them as close to in half as possible. Any idea how to modify you code for this?

Comment: You could just do a for loop starting from that index and see how far you can push it back. That way, it O(n) so it’s not that bad.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have it now